# Error installing urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, urllib3

I am using the command `pip install urllib3`, the error trace I am getting is as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could also try `pip install urllib3 version=2.4.0`. Replace `2.4.0` with a version you know exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which pip version do you use?

Try first to run the command `pip install --upgrade pip`

After that, when your pip version is up-to-date try to install the urllib3.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can grab the latest source code from GitHub:

> git clone [git://github.com/shazow/urllib3.git](http://git://github.com/shazow/urllib3.git)
>
> python setup.py install

Comment: When I am trying to update pip, again the connection gets aborted, but at the bottom I get a requirement already up to date message.

Have added the snapshot in question.

Comment: @SarangManjrekar ,  Have you tried this? `pip install urllib3  version=1.19.1`

Comment: Using this, its giving a different error, I have no idea about. Updated the snapshot in question.

Comment: The version is 1.19.1, not 2.4.01.19.1 @SarangManjrekar. And if this not working as well, you can try to use the git clone, Iv'e added the relevant git to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full traceback, this looks like your computer cannot resolve the addresses for `pypi.python.org` or `pypi.org` (I dont' know what version of pip you're using).

This could be because of a proxy issue or some other internet connectivity issue. There is literally no way for someone to help you debug this without more information.

Finally

```
pip install urllib3 version=2.4.0
```

Does not do what you think. What you told pip to do was install urllib3 and install a package named `version`. If you want a specific version you need to write

```
pip install urllib3==1.4.0
```

Or whatever version you need.