# How to be notified on telepot error?

Tags: python, telegram, telepot

My telegram bot consists of a telepot `DelegatorBot`. When the internet connection goes down, telepot notices, throws an error, catches it (so I assume) and retries.
How can I notice that an error happened and log accordingly, without just redirecting stdout to a file?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/loop.py", line 60, in run_forever
    allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 993, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 148, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 321, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot516341178:AAFcm4EYHvQerSCmzhcRhngEEd0he2GF07Q/getUpdates (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x75c26c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

[The docs](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=MaxRetryError&check_keywords=yes&area=default) don't seem to cover `MaxRetryError`

Comment: You should open issue instead of asking here

Comment: @Sean How to decide what to open as an issue and what not? It's not a bug - it's just me not understanding how to do what i want

Comment: use pip install urllib3==1.24.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112605/error-installing-urllib3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your issue but I was working just yesterday on something similar.

my code to get the error is  :

```
try:
    browserSelenium.startThreadBrowserStartLiking(chat_id, hoursToCatchUp)
    ex = ''
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    ex = '%s\nIF YOU SAW THIS MESSAGE, PLEASE COPY THIS TEXT AND CONTACT AN ADMIN!!!' % e
```

and when I sant a message I alway send `ex` to de end of the message.

You could implement the notification message into the `except` with something like

```
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Error: \n%s' % ex)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt this would work for my use case. The exception I get is from a thread that is spawned by the library and it catches the exception itself.

Comment: @lucidbrot did you try to run the function from a second file and then get the exception from the first?
Another solution could be to import the library inside the function (handling try and except to the function) and try to work your solution from there.

Comment: telepot internally launches a new thread that sometimes gets an exception, but catches that exception and only prints it. Hence, your suggestions wont work

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe try to just use a `try except` clausule to send myself a Telegram message with the debugging text whenever the error happens. I mean, we're already on Telegram, huh?

```
try:
    # whatever may cause an error
except:
    bot.sendMessage("YOUR_USER_ID","THE_ERROR_MESSAGE")
```